# IFRAME content is not showing in FIREFOX only

Tags: firefox, iframe

Here is the link http://buxle.com/game/aqua-thief 
I am not very professional but a good webmaster.
Below is the lately simple iframe code i use, please note that there is not any object, embed, scripted iframe code style left i have not tried but somehow cotent is not showing only in firefox, nothing found at firebug and other checkers... already spent 2 days , no luck.

```
<iframe style="width:650px; border:0; height: 650px;" src="http://games.okijin.com/index.php?gameid=aquathief&s=root&m=0912&auto=1"></iframe>
```

I give up web design jobs for 2 years and when i returned , i see simple style of tags even changed...

How can i make it work?
FYI. when i frame in an empty page, it shows :), what is preventing in that page. Also it appears for another iframed content too, i hear voice but no display, i have checked if any possible opacity, z-index or floating problem but i could not find.

Thanks at all.
Regards,

Answer (score 0):

thanks for the suggestion, i know that, sorry it was not working.
It looks like to me firefox is trying to useless browser